# Sent emails (non-default Outlook account) also getting saved in wrong drafts folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

We have several clients still on legacy hosted Exchange 2013 systems, and one end-user is experiencing a very strange issue.  She has two email accounts set-up in Outlook (different domains, but both hosted by same Exchange hosting provider) and sporadically she is getting emails that she sends from one account saved in the drafts folder of the other account.  The email also gets saved in the Sent Items of the correct account, but it seems like somehow it gets put in the drafts folder and then never moved.

It seems to happen mostly with attachments, and seems to relate to the default account and then switching to the other email account.  I am able to recreate the issue by locating a file on her hard drive, right-clicking and doing "Send to -> Mail Recipient" and then changing the FROM of this email to the other (non-default) account and sending it to myself.  This sent email gets correctly put in the Sent Items folder for the non-default account it was sent from, but also winds up in the drafts folder of the default email account.

I've tried recreating the entire Outlook profile and adding back both email accounts, and this doesn't help.  End-user is running MS Office Pro Plus 2016.  "File -> Options -> Mail -> Save messages -> When replying to a message that is not in the Inbox, save the reply in the same folder" is unchecked.  Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to fix?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests, I can reproduce your issue in my Outlook as well. Personally, I think this might be related to that you are not sending with the default email account. Similar issues will not happen if you sending from the default email account. I did some search about that but could not found any document to explain this.

As a workaround, it is suggested to set the email account you want to use as default email account. Or, you can try to add these two email accounts into two different Outlook profiles to avoid issues like this.

Comment: Glad to hear it's reproducible.  Separate Outlook profiles won't work for this end-user, and they do have their main account set as default but sometimes want to send from the other account and then occasionally this issue pops up.

Comment: Seems that there is no better way except for manual remove the draft messages. Fortunately, this seems does not make much troublesome.